# Send Client Certificate with POST Request - Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured, client-certificates

I am using Rest Assured for API Automation. How it works -

1. First, POST call is made to a URL (say 'abc'), to get the access token.
2. Then this access token is used to run other required API calls.

The issue is - To run the first call ('abc'), client certificate is required, which is already provided. With respect to certificate, we have -

1. .cer file
2. .key file
3. passphrase

Now, running the first call in Postman works fine, as I provided the Certificate, key and passphrase in Postman Settings.

But the issue is arising when running the same call in Rest Assured. Response says that client certificate was not sent with the Request.

Please suggest, how can we run this call successfully using Rest Assured?

**Note** - I have tried importing the certificate in jre cacerts file, tried creating a new keystore and using sslconfig keystore, truststore methods to access the .cer, .key files. But nothing works.

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/SSLITest.java

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solved it?